# Capture output with Apache2 and use PHP to parse it

Tags: php, apache2

I decided to code a website where each rewritten URL has its own file, instead of parsing them all with one file. Now, I want to capture output generated by any file, and use PHP to parse it ( beautify it, shrink it ). Is this possible?

I remember doing this with CSS and JS code to GZip them, but I can't remember what technique I used.

Thanks,
Sanil

Comment: About which kind of parsing (in the first sentence) do you speak?  How does a file generates output in your case? Normally files only contain data and they don't create output by just lying on the disk. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I meant that all URLs are rewritten to index.php, which would handle the output. I'd was thinking of avoiding that, although I might change my mind.

Comment: So you ask for a post-processing output filter for your PHP scripts?

Comment: Output filter for output generated by PHP scripts.

Comment: There you go: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php - You can do this for one or multiple scripts.

Comment: That's not what I wanted to achieve. I use output buffering at this point too. I think it would be impractical in this case, as I would need to have it in each file, I mean, multiple repetitions of the same code. I think I will cancel this idea, and use something that is proven to work. Thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: Duplicate code? You know that there is [`include`](http://php.net/include) and friends and you have [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file)?

Comment: Guess what, auto_prepend_file was what I was looking for. I knew it was named something like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file). You can register an output filter in that file that then automatically jumps into action.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you could do something like this:

In an `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will send any request that matches an actual file to your index.php. And then in the PHP script you open the file that's being requested, parse it however you want, and print the desired output.

Comment: I was using that in the old version. I thought this might be better. What would you suggest me on how to parse those URLs? I used some custom written functions, that mostly work on principle of splitting the URL at every "/".

Comment: It depends on the URLs you'll be working with. Splitting by '/' is not such a bad idea. You might want to work with PHP functions to handle paths (`dirname`, `basename`, etc.). You can also check out a routing scheme like Zend Framework's.